# Not getting form values because of some jquery validation script

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I write some jQuery script in form validation file to disable Submit button if data is valid.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    jQuery("#frmAddEditForm").validate({
        errorElement:'div',
        rules: {
            fname: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            fname: {
                required: "Please enter name"
            }
        }
    });

    $('#frmAddEditForm').submit(function(){
        if ($(this).valid()) {
          $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });

});
```

and Checking submit

```
if(strlen($this->input->post('submit'))>0)
{ 
  // Insert form data
}
```

I also tried

```
if($this->input->post('submit'))
{ 
      // Insert form data
}
```

But Nothing works.

if I change

```
$('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

to

```
$('#submit').css('display', 'none');
```

Then it works, But I want submit to be disabled.

Comment: I have updated my amswere please check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled inputs won't get posted. Workaround:

Create a hidden field and check for that to get posted:

```
<input type="hidden" name="posted" />
```

Then in PHP

```
if($this->input->post('posted'))
```

Or use any other non-disabled input you already have like `fname`. Should work.

Answer (score 1):

you are accessing wrong parameter in if i.e

```
 if($this->input->post('submit'))
```

submit is a button right, use **fname** in if

```
 if($this->input->post('fname'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please edit this as follows

//Set button disabled

```
   $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: Yes it disabled the submit but the problem with this method is I'm not getting my form data. It is not even coming in if condition.

Comment: That means your condition is not satisfied